# Shell commands using Cmake add_custom_command on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, cmake, post-build

I can't figure out the right syntax to run a shell command in a post-build step in Cmake on Linux. I can make a simple `echo` work, but when I want to e.g. iterate over all files and `echo` those, I'm getting an error.

The following works:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME}
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND echo Hello world!
                   USES_TERMINAL)
```

This correctly prints `Hello world!`.

But now I would like to iterate over all `.obj` files and print those. I thought I should do:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} 
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND for file in *.obj; do echo @file ; done 
                   VERBATIM
                   USES_TERMINAL)
```

But that gives the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations with quotation marks or starting with `sh`, but none of that seems to work. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `$file` or `bash -c "$(for file in *.obj; do echo $file ; done)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_custom_command` (and all the other CMake functions that execute a `COMMAND`) don't run shell scripts, but only allow the execution of a single command. The `USES_TERMINAL` doesn't cause the command to be run in an actual terminal or allow the use of shell builtins like the `for` loop.

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html):

> To run a full script, use the configure_file() command or the file(GENERATE) command to create it, and then specify a COMMAND to launch it.

Or, alternatively, for very simple scripts you can do what @lojza suggested in the comment to your question and run the `bash` command with the actual script content as an argument.

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME}
  POST_BUILD 
  COMMAND bash -c [[for file in *.obj; do echo ${file}; done]]
  VERBATIM
)
```

Note that I deliberately used a CMake raw string literal here so that `${file}` is not expanded as a CMake variable. You could also use `bash -c "for file in *obj; do echo $file; done"` with a regular string literal, in which case `$file` also isn't expanded due to the lack of curly braces. Having copied and pasted bash code from other sources into CMake before I know how difficult it is to track down bugs caused by an unexpected expansions of CMake variables in such scripts, though, so I'd always recommend to use `[[` and `]]` unless you actually want to expand a CMake variable.

However, for your concrete example of doing something with all files which match a pattern there is an even simpler alternative: Use the `find` command instead of a bash loop:

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME}
  POST_BUILD 
  COMMAND find
    -maxdepth 1 
    -name *.obj 
    -printf "%P\\n"
  VERBATIM
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, proper scripting of the COMMAND could be performed using debugging.
Below the **error message** there is a point to the line which causes it. Something like

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_target.dir/build.make:57: CMakeFiles/my_target] Error 2
```

So, you can look into the line 57 of the file `CMakeFiles/my_target.dir/build.make` and find out the command which is actually placed into the Makefile:

```
CMakeFiles/my_target:
    for file in "*.obj" do echo @file done
```

As you can see, CMake drops all semicolons (`;`): this is because this symbol is a separator for CMake.

Quoting semicolons doesn't help in VERBATIM mode:

The commmand

```
COMMAND for file in *.obj ";" do echo @file ";" done
```

is transformed

```
CMakeFiles/my_target:
    for file in "*.obj" ";" do echo @file ";" done
```

But shell doesn't treat quoted semicolons (`";"`) as commands separator!

Omitting VERBATIM gives better transformation:

```
CMakeFiles/my_target:
    for file in *.obj ; do echo @file ; done
```

The next step is to properly refer to the `file` variable in the script (`@` is definitely a wrong way). A script should see either `$file` or `${file}`, but **both** CMake and Make have a special way for process a dollar (`$`). (`VERBATIM` could automatically escape things for the Make, but we cannot use it because of semicolons.)

Resulted command could be either

```
COMMAND for file in *.obj ";" do echo $$file ";" done
```

or

```
COMMAND for file in "CMake*" ";" do echo $\${file} ";" done
```

---

As you can see, even VERBATIM doesn't handle all situations correctly.